# CSRF Token error when attempting to post from CURL to an API endpoint I control. How do I write the request?

Tags: django, curl, csrf

I have not utilized this part of Django before, but I have an endpoint which is giving me a 403 error and is telling me that my request needs a csrf token.  I was trying to figure out how best to get this since I was attempting to set up a bunch of curl requests to handle some simple queries to the endpoint.  Likewise, I was thinking to also use POSTman, but I was not sure where documentation is to handle these request.

I have seen the cookie csrftoken, but when I was attempting to curl with it, it was still giving me a 403.  thought it would looking something like this:

```
curl -d @profilepicturev2.png -b "csrftoken=Ebfn2OlfhSwFjAEQdoQon7wUjbynFoJqrtHMNPla3cy7ZfCMT9cxZ3OQHsbaedam" http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/files/uploader
```

Maybe I am mistaken?  I am trying to send a photo to the server, so i was thinking that this would be correct and wasnt sure if i needed to add additional params in order to append additional data information.

Answer (score 0):

i need to see your code, but i think you need to install "pillow" to send pictures in django !

Comment: There can be a lot of code.  It seems like you would mostly need to see some basic configuration of the Django server presumably.  I should be able to do that

Comment: Yes that would be a start, and i need the settings.py too, hope you solved it by now anyway !